# After switching from file to session vars the functions don't work

Tags: php, file, session

I have two methods which work without problems

```
public static function appendGamer($gamer) {
    file_put_contents(self::$fileName, $gamer, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

and

```
    private function selectLastGamer() {
        $gamers = file(self::$fileName);
        if (sizeof($gamers) > self::$totalGamers) {
            self::$totalGamers = sizeof($gamers);
            return trim($gamers[self::$totalGamers - 1]);
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Now I want everything to be stored in session vars rather than traditional text files. So i rewrite these functions the following way

```
public static function appendGamer($gamer) {
    $old = trim($_SESSION["gamers"]);
    $_SESSION["gamers"] = ($old == "") ? $gamer : $old . PHP_EOL . $gamer;
}
```

and

```
 private function selectLastGamer() {
        $gamers = explode(PHP_EOL, $_SESSION["gamers"]);
        if (sizeof($gamers) > self::$totalGamers) {
            self::$totalGamers = sizeof($gamers);
            return trim($gamers[self::$totalGamers - 1]);
        }
       return "";
    }
```

But now these functions don't work. I mean now `selectLastGamer` always returns empty string. The session variable is automatically created in constructor so it is always set. What's wrong with new version of these functions?

Comment: is the session started ?

Comment: Sorry, that was copy-paste error!! I changed the line with trim() in the question. Session has been started

Comment: Try to var_export SESSION array after updating

Comment: It shows only one gamer

Comment: @EtienneLeix Is it correct? If yes, you can to test self::$totalGamers value. may be `if` is always false

Comment: When I use the file-based previous versions of functions everything is OK. maybe I append new gamer to session var in wrong way?

Comment: I understood - you used one file for all players. But session accessible for one user. While connection exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start session on every page like

```
if( session_status() != PHP_SESSION_DISABLED )
{
    session_start();
}
```

OR

```
if( session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE || session_status() == PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE)
{
    session_start();
}
```

Because session_status() returns any one of the following value at a time.

PHP_SESSION_DISABLED if sessions are disabled.

PHP_SESSION_NONE if sessions are enabled, but none exists.

PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE if sessions are enabled, and one exists.

Hope it ll work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Start session on every page you want to access the session variable set/get using `session_start();` at the top of the page.

On main page and also on the page where functions are defined.

Comment: I have `if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}` on every page

Comment: Try using 
if( session_status() != PHP_SESSION_DISABLED )
{ session_start(); }